# Eclipse plugin update site as zip archive

Tags: eclipse-plugin, offline-caching

I've created an update site for my plugin using [this tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_update_site_%28site.xml%29%3F).
My update site works perfectly fine when installing from the folder, but when I put it into a zip and try to install "from archive", eclipse seems to treat it as a jar file.

Is there an option to correctly distribute a plugin as zip file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are creating an old-style update site (ie- pre- Eclipse 3.4 using site.xml and not using p2).

You need to generate p2 metadata for your update site.  Take a look at this tutorial for the simplest way to create a p2-aware update site:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseP2Update/article.html

p2 is the Eclipse provisioning system and it is the component that is used to find and install plugins and features into Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks, works fine.
PS: Yes, idk what happened to my link... ;-)

Comment: Yes, edited the question with the proper link. The '?' was giving people trouble.